# Javafx - What would the common way be to pre-load external data from a databse?

Tags: java, database, oop, javafx, static

I am pretty new to Javafx so saying already sorry if this may be an obvious question. I am using a Main class to do some housekeeping and pre-load the content from two json files so that everytime the app needs to get data, it does not need to read the file. Seems to me being the most efficient way. Then whenever the business logic needs the data it can call the static list and it's right there. But it seems completely against the entire OOP paradigm and it is already giving me a headache when trying to mock this for testing. So what is the common way of doing it out there?

1) How to pre-load a database at the very start of the program without it being hard later to access?

2) How to stay OOP and make that pre-load object persistent over the entire run of the app?

The data in the json are strings that need to be compared against incoming data over TCP in real time. Thus the need to be efficient. Sorry if this has been answered already but I can't seem to find a fitting strategy or patters that will solve this.

```
    public static List<DrefData> database;
    public static List<LayoutData> layout;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Initialize.logReportLevel("trace");

        // load databases
        DrefDataIO io = new DrefDataIO();
        LayoutDataIO lio = new LayoutDataIO();
        database = io.loadDatabase();
        layout = lio.loadLayoutDatabase();

        // open main window
        MainWindow.main(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to implement is a simple cache, an in memory representation of your database which is fast to access:

1. You need to implement the [Singleton Pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/singleton). This will ensure you only have an instance of your database object accessible to everyone in the same context. This will make it way easier to access since you will have a single object dedicated for that instead of it being in the Main class.
2. Although this solves both of your problems, it violates the single responsibility principle and will still be tricky to mock since a singleton must have the constructor private so it is only called by a named constructor once (not a Java expert but look at PowerMock i think it allows it).

Also, do you change your json in runtime? or is it a read-only

Comment: My json is luckily enough read-only but contains hundreds of strings that need to be mapped agsint incoming data.

Comment: Then you will not have cache validation problems :) I highly recommend you to read the link I attached, it even has a pseudo-code explanation for a database, just like yours. After you implement the Singleton, simply call the named constructor from the Main method once, then add a reference to the singleton class in every class you need it and access it in a static manner.